# throwing error when trying to access hashmap with key with a numeric value or special chars

Tags: thymeleaf

throwing an error when trying to access hashmap with key with a numeric value or special chars
Here is the code I am trying to use:

`<div th:include="${myMap[__${dept.code}__]}"/>`

If code has letters , this works fine, but if it holds only a numeric value "1234" , this fails .

Appreciate any resolution on this. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If the map is based on string keys you shpuld ensure that the precomputed expression is always a string.

A TextLiteral expression can only consist of a limited type of characters. A-z, underscores, minus and some others.

To ensure it's always a string you can wrap the precomputed expression in single quotes:

```
<div th:include="${myMap['__${dept.code}__']}"/>
```